# OneToOne-Relation to two entities implementing an interface

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with entity setup in Doctrine 2.3 (using Symfony 2).

There is a class 'Product' that has a field 'producer'.
Now this producer can either be a single person (class 'User') or a group (class 'Group').

What I wanted to do, is now have the User- and Group-class implement an interface 'Producer' and then have my $producer-Field map to the Producer-interface.

```
/**
 * @var Producer
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="..\..\Entity\Producer")
 */
private $producer;
```

This however fails with the message:

```
"Column name `id` referenced for relation from ..\..\Entity\Product towards 
..\..\Entity\Producer does not exist.
```

After giving it a second thought, this seems obvious - but now I'm wondering, how I can solve the problem. Because if I hadn't to use any persistence and just use PHP/Java/whatever, this approach would work - but when mapping to a DB, life is more complicated :-)

Inheritance is not a solution because 'User' already extends class 'Person' and has no similarity to 'Group' and as there is no such thing as multiple inheritance in PHP...

So, what would be a clean solution for this problem?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986318/relation-to-interface-in-doctrine
Unfortunately no answer there aswell.

Answer (score 1):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

this documentation should help you. Not sure it is the correct answer to your problem